# How make my Regex to match overlaps without infinity error?

Tags: regex

I have a sentence like: *"I'm won't sure if this will work for me"*

Now, I have this regex: `(\w+[']?\w{0,2})([ -])((\w+[']?\w{0,2}))`

If i'm trying to run this Regex over the sentence, i get these matches:

- I'm won't
- sure if
- this will
- work for

**Now, my goal is to get also these matches:**

- won't sure
- if this
- will work

---

If i'm trying to take the Regex and wrap it with `(?=(REGEX))`, I get an error that says ***The expression can match 0 characters, which can lead to infinite***. How can I get every match that I showed?

**NOTE:** I don't want the match "for I'm", which is a combo of the last word with the first words, only the matches from the beginning till the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If supported, you can assert a whitespace boundary to the left, and use a capturing group inside a positive lookahead.

If the word can not end on `'` you could use `\w+(?:'?\w+)?` instead of `\w+[']?\w{0,2}`

```
(?<!\S)(?=(\w+(?:'\w+)?[ -]\w+(?:'?\w+)?))
```

The pattern will match

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `(` Capture **group 1** (This contains the values)

    - `\w+(?:'\w+)?[ -]\w+(?:'?\w+)?`
  - )` Close group 1
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/terusr/1) | [Scala demo](https://ideone.com/Uf4Kby)

In Scala

```
val pattern = """(?<!\S)(?=(\w+(?:'\w+)?[ -]\w+(?:'?\w+)?))""".r
val text = "I'm won't sure if this will work for me"
pattern.findAllMatchIn(text).foreach(m => println(m.group(1)))
```

Output

```
I'm won't
won't sure
sure if
if this
this will
will work
work for
for me
```

Comment: Not clear but I think OP does not want to match `for me` at the end.

Comment: @dawg I do see "I don't want the match `for I'm`", but not `for me`

Comment: Still give me Infinite Error

Comment: @bar_boko what is the tool or language?

Comment: @bar_boko I have added a Scala demo to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you are describing:

```
/([a-zA-Z']+[ -](?=([a-zA-Z']+)))/g
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/U4Fvs2/2/)

Perl demo:

```
echo "I'm won't sure if this will work for me" | 
  perl -lne 'while (/([a-zA-Z\047]+[ -])(?=([a-zA-Z\047]+[ -]))/g) {print "$1$2"}'

I'm won't 
won't sure 
sure if 
if this 
this will 
will work 
work for
```